# How do I install certs in a firefox snap install?

Tags: firefox, snap

I have an ansible playbook that installs custom certs. Ubuntu 22.04 has defaulted to using a snap for firefox, so the following code isn't working.

```yaml
- name: Create Firefox policies.json
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /usr/lib/firefox/distribution/policies.json
    state: touch
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
- name: Configure Firefox certs
  copy:
    content: |
      {
        "policies": {
          "Certificates": {
            "ImportEnterpriseRoots": true,
            "Install": [
              "/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/Cert1.crt",
              "/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/Cert2.crt",
              "/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/Cert3.crt"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    dest: /usr/lib/firefox/distribution/policies.json
```

Changing the path to `/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/distribution` does not work. I get an error about that path being on a read only filesystem.

How can I get custom certs installed in a Firefox Snap?

Comment: You will need to remove the Firefox snap version and install the apt version.

Comment: Have you checked this page? https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/known-issues-with-firefox-snap/24663/19

Comment: @David, that's the conclusion I was coming to. I was hoping there was something I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Although the ImportEnterpriseRoots policy is reported not working in linux, as stated [here](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/v4.8/README.md#certificates--importenterpriseroots), I managed to get it working.

You should put the policies.json in `/etc/firefox/policies/` and you need to put the certificates in a place where the snap can see them, e.g. a sub-folder under `/etc/firefox/policies/`. For eg. `/etc/firefox/policies/certificates/`.
I propose that you create a symlink for that:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/ /etc/firefox/policies/certificates/
```

Although it's not a very good idea to link /usr/ folders with system folder in /etc/. I'm sure you get the point here.

Then, I believe your ansible playbook should go like this:

```
- name: Create Firefox policies.json
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /etc/firefox/policies/policies.json
    state: touch
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
- name: Configure Firefox certs
  copy:
    content: |
      {
        "policies": {
          "Certificates": {
            "ImportEnterpriseRoots": true,
            "Install": [
              "/etc/firefox/policies/certificates/Cert1.crt",
              "/etc/firefox/policies/certificates/Cert2.crt",
              "/etc/firefox/policies/certificates/Cert3.crt"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    dest: /etc/firefox/policies/policies.json
```